# Discord.js - JSON Parsing?

Tags: discord.js

Okay, I'm a bit new to JSON in Discord.js Bot Development, And I'm currently making a command where it grabs all of the data in a json file and splits it so it looks nicely formatted.

Currently have:

```
let Games = {
        "1": "Jailbreak",
        "2": "Adopt Me",
        "3": "Bubble Gum Simulator",
        "4": "Thick Legends",
        "5": "Arsenal",
        "6": "Legends Of Speed",
        "7": "Speed Champions",
        "8": "Build A Boat For Treasure",
        "9": "Boxing Simulator",
        "10": "Flight Simulator",
        "11": "Mad City",
        "12": "Redwood Prison",
        "13": "Horrific Housing",
        "14": "Welcome To Bloxburg",
        "15": "Tower Of Hell"
    }

    function getGames(lol) {
        lol = JSON.parse(Games[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]);
        for (let j in lol)  {
            return "• " + lol[j];
        }
    }
```

I want to group all of the Games and make it output:
"• example\n"

Any answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all object values, use `map` to add `•` and join it with `'\n'`.

**Like this:**

```js
    let Games = {
        "1": "Jailbreak",
        "2": "Adopt Me",
        "3": "Bubble Gum Simulator",
        "4": "Thick Legends",
        "5": "Arsenal",
        "6": "Legends Of Speed",
        "7": "Speed Champions",
        "8": "Build A Boat For Treasure",
        "9": "Boxing Simulator",
        "10": "Flight Simulator",
        "11": "Mad City",
        "12": "Redwood Prison",
        "13": "Horrific Housing",
        "14": "Welcome To Bloxburg",
        "15": "Tower Of Hell"
    }
    console.log(getGames(Games))
    function getGames(gameList) {
        return Object.values(gameList).map(game => `• ${game}`).join('\n')
    }
```

**Live example**

```js
let Games = {
    "1": "Jailbreak",
    "2": "Adopt Me",
    "3": "Bubble Gum Simulator",
    "4": "Thick Legends",
    "5": "Arsenal",
    "6": "Legends Of Speed",
    "7": "Speed Champions",
    "8": "Build A Boat For Treasure",
    "9": "Boxing Simulator",
    "10": "Flight Simulator",
    "11": "Mad City",
    "12": "Redwood Prison",
    "13": "Horrific Housing",
    "14": "Welcome To Bloxburg",
    "15": "Tower Of Hell"
}
console.log(getGames(Games))
function getGames(gameList) {
    return Object.values(gameList).map(game => `• ${game}`).join('\n')
}
```

Comment: I get `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. Do you know how I would make a !addgame and !removegame with that after?

Comment: for add you can use `game["number"] = 'some game'`
for delete you can use `delete game["number"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of the object values with Object.values()

```
let gamenames = Object.values(games)
```

Then,you can loop through the array elements to add them to a string.

```
let myString = "List: \n"
gamenames.forEach((val) => {
 myString += `• ${val} \n`
})
```

myString is now equal to an organized list of the games! It should look like:

List:
• Jailbreak
• Adopt me
...etc..

**(The list does put every single value on a seperate line,but StackOverflow doesn't want to show them properly for some reason)**

Hope this helped! If it did,please mark my question as a valid answer.